# How to write a CASE statement in DAX to return with a table expression

Tags: dax

I have a `DAX` statement, something like:

```
EVALUATE

SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
   TableName[FieldName1]
  ,TableName[FieldName2]
//I want to include a CASE statement here for my third column
)
```

With the behavior of `SUMMARIZE` and `SUMMARIZECOLUMNS`, I get errors when trying to use a CASE like statement here with either `SWITCH` or `IF`, which I assume is because of the way `SUMMARIZE` groups by. Unless you use an aggregate in the `SUMMARIZE`, there doesn't seem to be a simple way to include a derived column from a `CASE statement` in the output of `SUMMARIZE`. Has anyone worked through this problem?

Comment: The code of the CASE/IF would depends on what your condition looks like. Could you please add a pseudo-code which would describe your condition? Are you trying to filter by a value (if field3 = "C") or by measure (if field3 > 500)? Thanks

Comment: Is this a SQL query you are trying to recreate? If so, please share that as well.